# mapをプリントで表示する方法がいまいち分かりません

Tags: python, python3

mapを使って例えばリストをabsする場合に、変更後のリストをprintしようとすると、
`TypeError: 'list' object is not callable` とエラーが出ます。
どういう風に書けばエラーが出ないでしょうか？

```
list_test = [11, 0.3, -5, 3, -1]
print(list_test)

list_test_m = map(abs, list_test)
print(list_test_m)

print(list(list_test_m))
```

Comment: 解決できたなら[自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)を参考にしてみてください。未だほかに疑問点などあればコメントで

Answer (score 2):

以下のコードで同様のエラーが出ます
たぶん何処かで代入したのでしょう
(これに限らず `int`, `str`, `tuple`, `dict` なども代入すべきではない)

```py
list = [10,20]

print(list(list_test_m))
# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

削除すればよいです

```py
del list

print(list(list_test_m))
# [11, 0.3, 5, 3, 1]
```